# Refreshing NSURL Connection issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

my app sends data (a string) to my website via a NSURL Connection and from there I have a php script that uses the GET method to retrieve the data from the url that was sent from the iPhone. The script then searches the database and if a match is found, it output numbers (dates) to the website aka retrieved by the iPhone.

My issue is that when the user presses the button to "retrieve" the very first time, it works. But if they change the data and press the button once again, it retrieves the same information from the first time opposed to the new information it should be retrieving.

I think the problem may be that the NSURL Connection has to be reset the second time around hence why it is sending me duplicate data even though the user entered new data the second time. Does anyone know if this is the reason and if so how do you refresh a connection?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
        -(void) retrieveData: (id) sender //Method is called indirectly when the user presses the retrieve button
    {


  NSString *stringToBeSent;

//sender= [sender lowercaseString];

sender= [sender stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%20"];




[receivedData release];
receivedData= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
stringToBeSent= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://xxx.xxx.xxx./xxx/verification.php?Numbers=%@",sender];

// NSLog(@"annie %@", stringToBeSent);

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringToBeSent]];
Theconn= [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this with your code but a suggestion would be to set all the values to nil at the beginning onf the method.
So below "nsstring *stringtibesent" set this string and all other variables to nil, and then you'll later set them with a value anyways.